# Is it possible to create Dispatcher (System.Windows.Threading) for a non-UI worker thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Actually I want to have one dedicated worker thread for handling events from both main and other worker threads. This thread must also be able to invoke delegates in other threads. (The thread receives commands from the main thread, executes some of them in other worker threads, processes the completion and progress events from these commands, and inform the main thread about how he is doing).

All this could be done manually by implementing an analogue of the message queue from delegates in the desired thread. However, I would prefer a higher level approach if such exists. From the documentation I got the impression that the Dispatcher class is well suited for this purpose. I also got feeling that an object of this class can be created in any thread, but didn't find any example. Is my feeling wrong?

Comment: Message queue libraries [do exist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1529281/102937).

Comment: [`Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.currentdispatcher?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thank you very much. Now I see that this is the only correct approach. If you reword your comment as answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: My pleasure Ilia! I thought that it was a bit too trivial to post it as an answer. But if it answers your question sufficiently, here you have it. :-)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/blockingcollection-overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built-in, but it is quite easy to create a custom [`TaskScheduler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler) that schedules work on a specific thread. Most implementations use the handy [`BlockingCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1) class as a queue. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30719366/run-work-on-specific-thread) is one implementation, and [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/parallelextensionsextras-tour-5-stataskscheduler) is another one. You could customize any of these implementations to your needs, and then use it like this:

```
var myScheduler = new SingleThreadTaskScheduler();
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething(), default,
    TaskCreationOptions.None, myScheduler);
```

There is also the option to use the fancy [`TaskFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory) class, so that you can start tasks on this scheduler with less code:

```
var myFactory = new TaskFactory(new SingleThreadTaskScheduler());
var task = myFactory.StartNew(() => DoSomething());
```

Personally I am not a fan of this class, because it makes me confused with the similarity between `TaskFactory` and the [`Task.Factory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.factory) property.